# Multiprocessing in Python (going from a simple python for loop to multiprocessing for loop)

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I have never used multiprocessing module before.

I have a python script that works. It has a for loop that I would like to improve the execution speed by incorporating multiprocessing.

FYI: My Cpu has 8 cores, using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS, Python 3.6.8

The code without multiprocessing is as follows:

```
import math
import cmath
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

cj = cmath.sqrt(-1); Tp = 10e-6; Xc = 2e3; c = 3e8; B0 = 500e6; X0 = 50; fc = 2e9; ntarget = 8

w0 = 2 * cmath.pi * B0
wc = 2 * cmath.pi * fc
alpha = w0 / Tp
wcm = wc - alpha * Tp
Ts = (2 * (Xc - X0)) / c
Tf = (2*(Xc + X0))/c+Tp
dt = cmath.pi / (2 * alpha * Tp)
n = 2 * math.ceil(0.5 * (Tf - Ts) / dt)
t = Ts + np.arange(0, n * dt, dt)
dw = 2 * cmath.pi / (n * dt)
w = wc + dw * np.arange(-n / 2, n / 2)
x = Xc + 0.5 * c * dt * np.arange(-n / 2, n / 2)
kx = (2 * w) / c
xn = [0, 25, 35, 36.5, 40, -25, -35, -36.5]
fn = [1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 0.9, 1]
s = np.zeros((1, n))

for i in np.arange(ntarget):
    td = t - (2 * (Xc + xn[i]) / c)
    pha = wcm * td + alpha * np.power(td, 2)
    s = s + np.multiply(fn[i] * np.exp(cj * pha), np.logical_and(td >= 0, td <= Tp))
```

Based on the 's' output, the code further continues.

The second code block below is " with parallel processing " :

The upper code before "def work(ntarget)" remains same as the above code.

```
def work(ntarget):
    xn = [0, 25, 35, 36.5, 40, -25, -35, -36.5]
    fn = [1, 0.8, 1, 0.8, 1, 0.6, 0.9, 1]
    s = np.zeros((1, n))
    for i in np.arange(ntarget):
        td = t - (2 * (Xc + xn[i]) / c)
        pha = wcm * td + alpha * np.power(td, 2)
        s = s + np.multiply(fn[i] * np.exp(cj * pha), np.logical_and(td >= 0, td <= Tp))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    targets = [8]
    p = Pool()
    p.map(work, targets)

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

The first one works fine but the second, although the second code does run without error.

The execution time of the first code is "0.892 secs"

The execution time of the second code is "0.95 secs"

I expect the code to run in multiple cores to reduce the execution time.

Is something wrong with my multiprocessing code? or we cannot reduce the execution time further.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @ 0 0. Could be please provide me some example how to compile Numpy with OpenMp enabled and also converting the loop into a standard vectorised Numpy computation.

Comment: @0 0 I have changed the code and My goal is to run for loop in multiple cores and reduce the execution time of the code. Is there any solution?

Comment: Also, I assume you mean to focus on the actual calculation, not the plotting code (it's debatable whether you really want to speed up 0.892 seconds, which is already fast on a human scale; let's assume this is a test case). In that case, remove the unnecessary plotting code, since this distracts from the question and the actual essential code. See [mcve] about what I mean.

Comment: @ 0 0 Thanks for your valuable suggestions. Yes i want to parallelize for loop. and to utilize all the cores possible in my CPU.

Comment: Yeah sure you can ignore variables which are not in summation loop.

Comment: As I have mentioned in the question, the actual timings are around 0.815 to 0.890 secs.  The actual data input sizes of the variables in loop are: t is an array of [0, 21333], Xc is 2000, xn[i] is as mentioned above, c is 3e8, wcm is  9424777960.769379, td is an array of [0, 21333], alpha is 314159265358979.3, fn[i] is as mentioned in the question, pha is an array of [0, 21333].

Comment: Please do send me the code what you tried for parallelizing the for loop. So that I can show to my supervisor, that the speed-up is negative due to overhead of setting up the multiprocessing.

Comment: Thanks but my Master Thesis is based on multi-core processing so i would want to process the code in Multi-core processors so. Please do send the code.

Comment: @ 0 0 Now I have changed some part of the code by reducing targets, xn, fn values to 8 each respectively. Based on the number of targets, splitting the xn & fn values into different core. For Eg: Only 1st set of xn=0, fn=1 values should run in 1st core, IIly next set of xn=25, fn=0.8 should run in 2nd core and so on till 8th target and 8th core. I need some suggestions from you and Can you please  help me how to change the code according to it?